# Cosa significa "uva passera"?

Tags: meaning, regional

Nel romanzo *La luna e i falò*, di Cesare Pavese, ho letto:

> Il giorno che tornai al casotto di Gaminella, conoscevo già il vecchio Valino. L’aveva fermato Nuto in piazza in mia presenza e gli aveva chiesto se mi conosceva. Un uomo secco e nero, con gli occhi da talpa, che mi guardò circospetto, e quando Nuto gli disse ridendo ch’ero uno che gli aveva mangiato del pane e bevuto del vino, restò lí senza decidersi, torbido. Allora gli chiesi se era lui che aveva tagliato i noccioli e se sopra la stalla c’era sempre quella spalliera di **uva passera**.

Ho cercato il termine "passero" in parecchi dizionari, ma il significato che ho trovato (un uccello) non ha senso nel contesto del testo. Per questa ragione vi chiedo: sapreste spiegarmi cos'è questa "uva passera" che appare nel brano sopra citato? Si tratta forse di italiano regionale?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

L'uva passera è una particolare varietà di uva che ha gli acini senza semi.

Il [Sabatini-Coletti](https://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/P/passera_2.shtml?refresh_ce-cp) riporta:

> passera 2 
> [pàs-se-ra] agg.
>  uva p. (o come s.f. la p.), quella con gli
>   acini senza semi, nota anche come passerina, passeretta o uvetta sec.
>   XIV

Anche [questo post in un blog enogastonomico](https://larcante.com/tag/uva-passera/) riporta:

> La Passerina, il vitigno, ha una sua specifica identità, qua e là
>   viene chiamata da sempre con nomi a dir poco folcloristici
>   (cacciadebiti, cacchione, ***uva passera***, uva d’oro, uva Fermana) e
>   seppur non vanti nobili origini certe del suo nome, grazie alla sua
>   abbondante produttività ha saputo garantirsi una certa riconoscenza
>   che gli ha consentito di arrivare sino ai tempi moderni,

Questo [sito di enologia](https://www.vinook.it/uva-e-vitigni/vitigni-bianchi/passerina.asp) ne spiega l'origine:

> Il Passerina è un vitigno a bacca bianca autoctono dell’Italia
>   centrale, la cui provenienza esatta è contesa tra la provincia di
>   Frosinone e la regione Marche. Questa contesa è dovuta al fatto che si
>   tratta di un vitigno molto antico, coltivato in tutto il centro Italia
>   seppur con sinonimi diversi. Gli esperti comunque propendono tutti per
>   l'ipotesi marchigiana. Come genealogia appartiene alla famiglia dei
>   Trebbiani, e con essi è stato spesso confuso, così come con il Bombino
>   Bianco.

Comment: Avevo visto l'entrata "passero" sul Sabatini Coletti (e su altri dizionari), ma non questa entrata "passera". Tuttavia, l'uvetta non è l'uva secca?

Comment: E anche l'uva passa che hai aggiunto adesso... non è l'uva secca?

Comment: L'uvetta viene chiamata anche uva passa o uva sultanina ma penso che in questo caso uvetta si riferisca alla dimensione degli acini che nel caso dell'uva passera o passerina sono piccoli

Comment: Quindi, l'uva passa e l'uva passera col significato spiegato nel Sabatini Coletti non sarebbero la stessa cosa, no?

Comment: Da quello che si legge nei link che ho inserito, secondo me indicano due cose diverse: l'uva passa è quella disidratata che si usa nei dolci, mentre uva passera si riferisce ad una varietà di vitigno.

Comment: Lo dicevo per quel che si può leggere sul "Dizionario Botanico", informazione che, sinceramente, non mi sembra di molto aiuto.

Comment: Se "uva passa" e "uva passera", a quanto pare (perlomeno nel contesto della domanda), non hanno lo stesso significato, penso che l'entrata del dizionario Ottocentesco che hai aggiunto crei confusione. Secondo me, la tua risposta migliorerebbe togliendo questa ultima citazione (e sono disposta ad accettarla perché la voce del Sabatini Coletti risulta totalmente convincente).

Comment: @Charo citazione eliminata

Comment: Sentito oggi su un treno che andava da Rimini ad Ancona (il mio primo viaggio fuori dalla Spagna durante la pandemia!): un uomo spiegava a un'altro che quello che stava mangiando (senza la mascherina, ovviamente) era pandoro con l'uvetta passera. In questo caso sembra si tratti dell'accezione del dizionario Ottocentesco.