# Quando si usano "quel che" e "quello che"?

Tags: word-usage, difference, adjectives, apocope

La risposta a [questa domanda](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/5984/quello-or-quel-what-is-the-difference) dice che si usano le forme *quel* e *quello* come si usano gli articoli il e lo. Quindi, è più corretto scrivere "quel che"? Ho visto usate entrambe le forme "quel che" e "quello che".

Alcuni esempi:

> "Quello che mi ha detto non è vero." vs.
> "Quel che mi ha detto non è vero."
>
> "Sei contento di quello che hai?" vs.
> "Sei contento di quel che hai?"
>
> "dare a Cesare quello che è di Cesare" vs.
> "dare a Cesare quel che è di Cesare"

Comment: Benvenuto su ItalianSE!!! Puoi fare qualche esempio su cui hai dubbi?

Comment: Ho aggiunto alcuni esempi.

Comment: Il grosso della risposta che citi e della voce Treccani riguarda l'uso di “quello” come aggettivo (quello stivale, quel cane); in “quello che (mi hai detto)” è invece un pronome. Cercherò delle fonti, ma direi che i due usi siano perfettamente intercambiabili e che a guidare sia solo il gusto, nel caso che una delle due versioni sia più orecchiabile dell'altra, un po' come in altri casi di troncamento (andare via/andar via etc.).

Comment: Dal [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/quello/): «Come pron. conserva quasi sempre la flessione regolare; solo al masch. sing. possono trovarsi, accanto alla forma d’uso com. *quello*, le forme letter. *quegli* e *quei* (per le quali v. le voci), e *quello* può inoltre subire troncamento quando è seguito dal pron. relativo *che*, spec. se ha valore neutro (per es.: *faccio quel che mi pare*).»

Answer (score 3):

Gli aggettivi *bello* e *quello* sono molto particolari in italiano, perché hanno forme simili a quelle degli articoli e delle preposizioni articolate:

> bel bello bei begli
>   quel quello quei quegli

Quindi *il tavolo/quel tavolo*, *lo gnomo/quello gnomo*, *l'amico/quell'amico*, *i tavoli/quei tavoli*, *gli gnomi/quegli gnomi*.

Se usati in forma pronominale, i plurali sono *belli* e *quelli*:

> *Che belli!*
>   *Quali hai scelto? Quelli.*

<sup>Per il femminile le forme sono solo *bella/belle* e *quella/quelle* (con eventuale elisione).</sup>

Le forme “articolate” sono comunemente usate (obbligatorie) quando l'aggettivo precede un sostantivo o un aggettivo sostantivato (*un bel po'*). Davanti a un pronome, la scelta è diversa: per esempio, non si dice **quei che*, ma *quelli che*. La prima forma non è “scorretta”, ma antiquata, e si trova certamente in scritti, in particolare prima della seconda metà del XIX secolo.

La scelta fra *quel* e *quello* davanti a un pronome è essenzialmente libera, ma al giorno d'oggi direi che tende a prevalere *quello* eccetto che in frasi cristallizzate.

Un ottimo riferimento standard è http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/quello/ (come proposto da Charo in un commento).

Comment: Siccome non sono italiana, veramente non ho idea sulle tendenze della lingua italiana moderna. Tuttavia, mi sembra ricordare di aver letto molte volte nei vostri commenti espressioni come "per quel che vale".

Comment: @Charo È un'espressione cristallizzata, come la più antica *per lo più* in cui si usa l'articolo “sbagliato”, ma che era comune nell'italiano antico (Dante, Boccaccio e Petrarca, per esempio).

Comment: È possibile che l'uso di *quel che* vs *quello che* vari anche su base regionale, il Nord Italia tende a essere più tollerante dei troncamenti rispetto al Centro Sud. Difficile essere più precisi senza uno studio dettagliato.

Comment: Infatti, quando ho scritto uno dei commenti a [questo post](https://italian.stackexchange.com/a/10487/707) («Lo dicevo ***per quel che*** si può leggere sul "Dizionario Botanico" ...») ho avuto il dubbio se scrivere "per quel che" oppure "per quello che". D'accordo alla tendenza della lingua attuale, avrebbe suonato più naturale scrivere "per quello che"?

Comment: @Charo Userei *per quel che* in questo contesto, ma entrambi suonano abbastanza naturali e avrei problemi a dare una regola definitiva

Comment: “Si può dibattere se in quel/quello che ti pare si abbia un pronome o un aggettivo: roba da far accapigliare i grammatici.” Non capisco bene: ti riferisci a “quel(lo)”? Come può non essere un pronome? Basta pensare di sostituirlo con “ciò (che ti pare)”.

Comment: @DaG Esattamente come intendevo. Ma siccome non sono un grammatico, evito di litigare. `;-)`

Comment: @egreg: Anch'io non voglio litigare, volevo solo capire che cosa intendevi.

Comment: @DaG Se fosse sentito come pronome, nessuno avrebbe dubbi sull'uso di *quello*, che è ciò che accade nella lingua attuale.

Comment: @egreg: Inoltre, la frase del vocabolario Treccani che parla di questo fenomeno comincia con le parole «Come pron.», quindi, perlomeno come la capisco io, sta affermando che si tratta di un pronome.

Comment: @DaG Ho tolto, ma rimango della mia idea. :-)

Comment: «Quello» può essere usato come pronome, in «Quello è tutto matto.» In effetti, è tra i pronomi dimostrativi.

Answer (score 1):

In generale la Treccani riguardo a [quello](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/quello_%28La-grammatica-italiana%29/) dice:

> La scelta tra le varie forme del maschile singolare (*quello*, *quell’*
>   con ➔elisione e quel con ➔troncamento), del femminile singolare
>   (*quella* e *quell’*) e del maschile plurale (*quei* e *quegli*) segue le
>   stesse regole che valgono per l’articolo ➔determinativo; come per
>   l’articolo determinativo, il femminile plurale ha un’unica forma,
>   *quelle*

Ad esempio un’espressione in cui sono intercambiabili è la seguente:

> Per quel/quello che ne so Mario è partito ieri

Come spiegato nella risposta che hai menzionato, quando quello è un pronome non puoi usare la forma quel:

> Non ho detto quello (non quel, che sarebbe errato)

In tutti gli esempi da te citati *quel* e *quello* sono intercambiabili.

Comment: Quindi non c'è nessuna differenza tra "quel che" e "quello che" (nel senso di "that which", "what" in inglese)? Sono sempre intercambiabili?

Comment: Non sempre, come mostrato nell’ultimo esempio della mia risposta

Comment: Però nell'ultimo esempio, non è usato "quello *che*" ma semplicemente "quello". Ho chiesto se "quello che" e "quel che" sono intercambiabili.

Comment: Scusa, errore mio di distrazione

Comment: Tuttavia, in "quel che", "quel" è un pronome. E il passo della Treccani che hai citato fa riferimento a "quello" come aggettivo.